# VBA Error Message: Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set. Can't See It

Tags: vba, excel

Line 22 is throwing the error (Set wbPath2)

This code is supposed to loop through each worksheet in my workbook and, as it loops, open another workbook related to the current loop iteration, then sum a column, then put that SUM in my original workbook. I'm getting and object error 91. I've been scratching my head for a while. Anyone know why this error message appears?

```
Private Sub PopulateData_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastDay As Long

lastDay = Day(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(ComboBox1.Value & Year(Date), 0))
monthNumber = Month(DateValue("01-" & ComboBox1.Value & "-1900")) 
Root = "C:\myDirectory\" & Year(Date) & "\" & 
        monthNumber & ". " & ComboBox1.Value & " " & Year(Date) & "\"

'TOTAL CARS PER WEEK
Dim wbPath2 As Object
sourceFile = monthNumber & ". " & ComboBox1.Value & " " & Year(Date)
sourceSheet = "\[" & ws.Name & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & 
               Format(Now(), "yy") & ".csv]"


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If (ws.Name <> "Master") And (ws.Name <> "Combined") Then
        Set wbPath2 = Workbooks.Open(Root & ws.Name & " " & monthNumber & 
                      "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & ".csv")
        With ws
            .Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total cars per 
            week", Range("A:A"), 0), 18).Formula = "=SUM('" & Root & 
            sourceFile & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & monthNumber & "." & 
            lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$H:$H)"
        End With

        wbPath2.Close
        MsgBox wbPath2
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what line of code is the error happening on?

Comment: It doesn't say. Jsut an error message Run-time error 91 Object or With block variable not set. Then i press Ok. no option to debug

Comment: What if you go through sub in debug mode? Put cursor somewhere within the code and press F8 to execute code line by line.

Comment: OH! It's happening right when the "For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets" hits

Comment: I would have expected it to occur on the line before that, where you are using `ws.Name` without having set `ws` to anything.

Comment: Note that the `Sheets` collection contains `Worksheet` objects, but also `Chart` objects, which will make your code throw another type of error if your workbook contains any. If you want to iterate worksheets, iterate the `Worksheets` collection.

Comment: You also have unqualified `Range` calls inside that `With` block - these are implicitly referring to whatever worksheet is currently active, and that's yet another bug / runtime error 1004 waiting to be thrown.

Comment: @SeanKelly Can you please confirm whether the error does occur on the line you said, or whether it occurs on the previous line.  I don't want to waste hours looking at this if I am not looking at the right error line.

Comment: @YowE3K Mat's Mug is right. I'll edit my submission with the solution

Comment: Also, [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) is your friend :D

Answer (score 3):

I had to `Set` the `ws` object to resolve run time 91 error. Look in the comments section for Mat's Mug's additional bug fixes.

```
Private Sub PopulateData_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Activesheet

    '...
```

Comment: I still can't see how that would have fixed an error at the `Set wbPath2` statement, which is where the question says the code crashed, because by the time it gets to that line `ws` is already set by the `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` line.  I still think your code must be crashing earlier, at the line using `ws.Name` before the loop starts.